# get table data with curl and regex

Tags: php, html, xpath, web-scraping, domdocument

this is my code to extract data from table.

but I want delete links.

and how pieces title and price to array.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init ("http://www.digionline.ir/Allprovince/CategoryProducts/cat=10301");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match('#<table[^>]*>(.+?)</table>#is', $page, $matches);
foreach ($matches as &$match) {
$match = $match;
}
echo '<table>';

echo  $match ;
echo '</table>';

?>
```

Comment: what is the final output?

Comment: extract product name and price // the language is persian

Comment: and put all the data inside the an array?

Comment: with top procedure can't extract in to array // I want extract data in to array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest use an HTML Parser instead. Use `DOMDocument` + `DOMXpath`, no need to install they are built-in already. Example:

```
$ch = curl_init ("http://www.digionline.ir/Allprovince/CategoryProducts/cat=10301");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($page);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$data = array();
// get all table rows and rows which are not headers
$table_rows = $xpath->query('//table[@id="tbl-all-product-view"]/tr[@class!="rowH"]');
foreach($table_rows as $row => $tr) {
    foreach($tr->childNodes as $td) {
        $data[$row][] = preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', '', trim($td->nodeValue));
    }
    $data[$row] = array_values(array_filter($data[$row]));
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

`$data` should contain:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => AMDA4-3400
        [1] => 1,200,000
        [2] => 1,200,000
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => AMDSempron 145
        [1] => 860,000
        [2] => 910,000
    )
```

Comment: How to update page every day with curl of course I Guess whit corn job can be update page .. but I don't know how work with that

Comment: please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696986/remove-first-or-specific-child-node-xpath

Comment: @Ghost thank you for this code but can you help me please with other structure of table ? Here is what i need : [example](http://bulkforme.eu.pn/stack.php). Regards

Comment: @Peacefull the idea is just the same, use curl to get the html, use `DOM` to parse the actual HTML

Comment: @Ghost yes i followed your actual code and works great to parse the HTML table but i can't manage it to return the title associate to the values. Can you give me an example please ?

Comment: its really helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you want parse some web resource, you can use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

If you want to get an table and all links inside table:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.digionline.ir/Allprovince/CategoryProducts/cat=10301');
$table = $html->find('table');
$links = $table->find('a');

echo $table;
```