# remove first or specific child node xpath

Tags: php, xpath, removechild

this code get table.

I want to remove first and second tr tag in the table.

```
$data = array();
$table_rows = $xpath->query('//table[@class="adminlist"]/tr');
if($table_rows->length <= 0) { // exit if not found
echo 'no table rows found';
exit;
}

foreach($table_rows as $tr) { // foreach row
 $row = $tr->childNodes;
if($row->item(0)->tagName != 'tblhead') { // avoid headers
    $data[] = array(
        'Name' =>trim($row->item(0)->nodeValue),
        'LivePrice' => trim($row->item(2)->nodeValue),
        'Change'=> trim($row->item(4)->nodeValue),
        'Lowest'=> trim($row->item(6)->nodeValue),
        'Topest'=> trim($row->item(8)->nodeValue),
        'Time'=> trim($row->item(10)->nodeValue),
    );
}
}
```

and question 2

In the bellow table tr have two class --- EvenRow_Print and OddRow_Print ---

```
     $data = array();
     $table_rows = $xpath->query('//table/tr'); 
     if($table_rows->length <= 0) { 
     echo 'no table rows found';
     exit;
          }

    foreach($table_rows as $tr) { // foreach row
 $row = $tr->childNodes;
if($row->item(0)->tagName != 'tblhead') { // avoid headers
    $data[] = array(
        'Name' =>trim($row->item(0)->nodeValue),
        'LivePrice' => trim($row->item(2)->nodeValue),
        'Change'=> trim($row->item(4)->nodeValue),
        'Lowest'=> trim($row->item(6)->nodeValue),
        'Topest'=> trim($row->item(8)->nodeValue),
        'Time'=> trim($row->item(10)->nodeValue),
    );
   }
 }
```

How can I echo both tr  in one 2d array .
examp.

```
       Array(

      [0] => Array(
     //array
                  )

}
```

Thank's

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. Asking two questions at once does not work on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1 - there are different ways to skip the first and last element, e.g. removing the first entry using `array_shift()` and the last entry using `array_pop()`. But as it's not clear if it'd be better to keep the array as it is, it's possible to skip both entries in the `foreach` in an easy way like using a counter, continuing for the first entry and breaking for the last:

```
 $i = 0;
 $trlength = count($table_rows);
 foreach( ...) {
   if ($i == 0)  // is true for the first entry
   { 
     $i++;       // increment counter
     continue;   // continue with next entry
   }
   else if ($i == $trlength - 1)   // last entry, -1 because $i starts from 0
   {
     break;      // exit foreach loop
   }
   ....         // handle all other entries
   $i++;        // increment counter in foreach loop
  }
```

Comment: In the foreach I have one if . and I don't know how set if ($i == 0) in the foreach.

Comment: The if that you already have shouldn't matter; just place above "if" before it; in case it's the first or last entry, the foreach will skip or break; in case it's not, it'll proceed to your following if  which should be added at my answer's part with the placeholder "... //handle all other entries"